# Creating an image border around images of variable size with CSS

Tags: html, css

I wish to put a border frame around an image - like a photo frame image. Is there an easy way to do this? I.e using CSS purely, ideally I'd like to recreate the 45 degree joins at the edge and be as realistic as possible. The snag here is that the image size is variable.

Comment: Does `img { 
   border:1px solid #E80C7A;
}` not work?

Comment: You can using `border-image` [**Border-image @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)...it is somewhat complex however and there are tools that can help you with that. If you have some specific image in mind for the border and some code, we can help further.

Comment: Give us a fiddle or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this webpage: http://cssdeck.com/labs/picture-frame-using-box-shadows

Run the snippet below to see how it works. It is purely CSS, no HTML and no JS involved. The effect is accomplished using the `box-shadow` property. Of course, with your code, you would need to include HTML and set the images' sizes (or keep them in percentage - i.e. 100%) and then tweak the code a bit. The effect is created and works with different sized images, you just need to change the inset colour values to your preferred style.

```css
/* Pure CSS Picture Frame */

html {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #653845;
 background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(0,0%,0%,.1) 50%, transparent 50%),
                   linear-gradient(-45deg, hsla(0,0%,0%,.1) 50%, transparent 50%);
 background-size: .25em .25em;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 500px hsla(0,0%,0%,.5);
 height: 100%;
 padding: 1px;
}

body {
 height: 300px;
 width: 400px;
 margin: -150px -200px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 background: gray url(http://dribbble.com/system/users/13774/screenshots/423481/_111.jpg?1329144172);
 border: 1px solid;
 border-color: #bbb #999;
 box-shadow: 
  0 2px 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.4),
 
  inset 0 1px 0 #ccc, 
  inset 1px 0 0 #aaa,
  inset 0 -1px 0 #ccc,
  inset -1px 0 0 #aaa,
   
  inset 0 2px 0 #c6c6c6,
  inset 2px 0 0 #a6a6a6,
  inset 0 -2px 0 #c6c6c6,
  inset -2px 0 0 #a6a6a6,
  
  inset 0 3px 0 #c0c0c0,
  inset 3px 0 0 #a0a0a0,
  inset 0 -3px 0 #c0c0c0,
  inset -3px 0 0 #a0a0a0, 
  
  inset 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
  inset 4px 0 0 #999,
  inset 0 -4px 0 #b9b9b9,
  inset -4px 0 0 #999,
  
  inset 0 5px 0 #b6b6b6,
  inset 5px 0 0 #969696,
  inset 0 -5px 0 #b6b6b6,
  inset -5px 0 0 #969696,
  
  inset 0 6px 0 #b0b0b0,
  inset 6px 0 0 #909090,
  inset 0 -6px 0 #b0b0b0,
  inset -6px 0 0 #909090,
  
  inset 0 7px 0 #a9a9a9,
  inset 7px 0 0 #898989,
  inset 0 -7px 0 #a9a9a9,
  inset -7px 0 0 #898989,
  
  inset 0 8px 0 #a6a6a6,
  inset 8px 0 0 #868686,
  inset 0 -8px 0 #a6a6a6,
  inset -8px 0 0 #868686,
  
  inset 0 9px 0 #a0a0a0,
  inset 9px 0 0 #808080,
  inset 0 -9px 0 #a0a0a0,
  inset -9px 0 0 #808080,
  
  inset 0 10px 0 #888,
  inset 10px 0 0 #666,
  inset 0 -10px 0 #888,
  inset -10px 0 0 #666,
  
  inset 0 0 10px 10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.5);
}
```

P.S. to further style your photos, you can add a bevel effect. Google (or whatever search engine you prefer) how to do this if you aren't familiar with it yourself, when I searched for "CSS image bevel" lots of resources were available and many ways to create the effect exist.

Hopefully this is what you're looking for! Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Until some point you can do that with CSS3 http://border-image.com/ generator.